# Zero divisor on $S/I$ when $\mathrm{depth}(S/I) >0.$

Tags: commutative-algebra, hilbert-polynomial

> Consider the polynomial ring $S=K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$, where $K$ is a field and let $I \subset S$ be a homogeneous ideal under standard grading. If $\mathrm{depth}(S/I) >0$, then how can I show that there exists $x \in S_1$ which is a non-zero divisor on $S/I$?

One thing I understand that Hilbert polynomial being a non-zero polynomial $I \cap S_1 \neq S_1$, in fact more than that $I \cap S_m \neq S_m$ $\forall\ m \geq 0.$ But then I can't proceed further.

Help me. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you want $K$ an *infinite* field.

Comment: If $k$ is finite is it false ?

Comment: $K=\mathbb F_2$, $n=2$, and $I$ generated by $X_1X_2(X_1+X_2)$.

Comment: Thanks..so one has to assume that k is infinite. But then how to prove that ?

Comment: Bruns and Herzog, Proposition 1.5.12.

Comment: I want to point out one thing: In that proposition it is given that the homogeneous ideal is generated by degree 1 elements. Here it is not given.

Comment: @user26857 Doesn't this work? If $S_1$ consists of zerodivisors on $S/I$ then $S_1$ equals the union of $P_i \cap S_1$ where $P_i$ are associated primes of $I$. But a vector space over an infinite field is not a finite union of proper subspaces. So $S_1 \cap P_i = S_1$ for some $i$ and then $P_i = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is an associated prime of $I$ so $S/I$ has depth 0